# Trying to understand GTM Docs

Tags: google-tag-manager

A client of us is asking us to move to server side tagging on GTM.
So I created a container, I verified the domain and all of that, then I followed this:

https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/send-data

```
Once the server container URL is set, data is sent to a client in your Tag Manager server-side container. By default, GA4 and a UA clients are pre-installed on your server-side container.
Key Term: "Clients" are adapters between the software running on a user's device and your server-side Tag Manager container. They receive measurement data from a device, transform that data into one or more events, process the data in the container, and package the results to be sent back to the device.

In your Tag Manager server container, click Clients in the left navigation to view the list of clients. Click the name of the client to view or edit details. In most cases, the client will require no modifications. However, there are settings that may require edits for certain cases:
```

So now, my site (drupal) is sending events to a GTM web container as it always was, and that web container is firing the events on the server container and tags to GA4, and then the server container fires the events to GA4 again.

Isn't that redundant and pointless?
I thought the idea was to cut the middleman and try not to cross domain boundaries to prevent cookies from being blocked.

Am I reading the docs wrong? maybe I'm assuming this is the way it should be setup and instead this is just an example to get data from an existing feed?

Comment: I guess you can only leave the server side container only. Because at current situation. The GA4 or UA is receiving data from both containers. 
https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/send-data#google-analytics-4
Or if you are asking about this. Configure the web container UA and GA4 tags and make them send to your server side container by adding transport_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Darrellwan indicated, you don't need to use two containers in parallel.

What a lot of people are trying to do is to use the front-end GTM to send events about what happens to the page to the backend GTM.

Using front-end GTM in this case, however, is questionable since it's too easy to block with most of the adblockers. Therefore, people often just do tracking with arbitrary on-page JS, sending the details to the sGTM endpoint. But then the adblockers can block the sGTM endpoint, which is, too, not the best case scenario, so they deploy a proxying mirror endpoint on their backend that relays events to the sGTM endpoint.

As per cookies, there's very little cookie concern. GTM doesn't use third party cookies for tracking, so no issues on that front. And there are very few people who disable cookies in their browsers since that cuts off a lot of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If all you do is using GA4, then having a server-side GTM is a bit pointless; you still have to integrate a full GA4 installation on the client via GTM (because some GA4 events like session_start are only generated in the client-side GA4 code), so it does not even save you page weight by reducing JS code.

The situation changes somewhat when you have additonal marketing tags, since you do not have to send a request to server-side GTM for every tag, but instead can re-use the data from the GA request for other tags. With a bit of programming you can also convert javascript cookies to server-side cookies, which makes them a tad more robust against some ad blocking features, and you can redact e.g. personal data before you fire tags to a marketing vendor.

The limits are tags that interact with the website, or tags  that rely on 3rd party cookies (both not possible from a server-side container), so feedback tools, remarketing tags and similar cannot be used from a server-side container.

But yes, if all you want to do is to run GA4, then you do not need GTM at all (neither server-side nor client side) and would be better off with gtag.js (a sort of trimmed-down tag deployment solution for Google tags only).

Comment: actually what prompted this is that we were asked to deploy facebook pixels, so it seems it's a requierement to have a server container